# Java LinkedList ListIterator

Tags: java, listiterator

so what I'm trying to accomplish with my code is to read tasks off of a document with an end goal of sorting them by a priority (given from a separate class) into a LinkedList using a ListIterator. I have all of my tasks going into a LinkedList, however I've made a mistake somewhere in the organizing part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task newTask = null;
    LinkedList<Task> list = new LinkedList();
    TaskReader reader = new TaskReader("tasks.txt");

    list.add(reader.provideTask());
    ListIterator<Task> iter = list.listIterator();

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        newTask = reader.provideTask();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            if (newTask.getPriority() <= iter.next().getPriority()) {
                iter.add(newTask);
            } else {
                iter.previous();
                iter.add(newTask);
                iter.next();
            }
        }
        iter = list.listIterator();
    }
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next().getPriority());
    }
}
```

Right now I am get a huge amount of output, where I should only be getting 20 lines (and they should be organized from 10-1 by priority given from separate class). Any help would be awesome! Thank you!
Below is the TaskReader class

```
package versionTwo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaskReader implements TaskProvider {

    private Scanner source = null;

    public TaskReader(String fileName) {
        try {
            source = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException er) {
            System.out.println("Error opening input file " + fileName + " for reading.");
        }
    }

    public Task provideTask() {
        Task newTask = null;
        if (source != null) {
            try {
                newTask = new Task(source.nextInt(), source.nextInt());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error while trying to read task.");
            }
        }
        return newTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `PriorityQueue`? Why aren't you just adding items to the list, and calling `list.sort()`? Or finding where to insert them using `Collections.binarySearch`?

Comment: I'm sure both of those are well suited for the task - but this is an assignment I have received and it is to become familiar with ListIterators my professor would like us to sort through the list, and calling .add() on the appropriate cursor selection

Comment: @C.Catt Can you post your TaskReader class, especially the method TaskReader.provideTask()?

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev the implementation is almost certainly unimportant. It's logically an `Iterator<Task>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well if TaskReader is a custom class then I could see it being important especially if it was contributing to the large amount of data in the output. But I agree with your strategy of finding an alternative solution to what OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev OP gets 20 items from it.

Comment: I agree the the strategy is a little clunky, it seems like a lot of redundant loops need to be used
edit: also added in the task reader class!

Comment: My thought is that I've messed up the cursor movement somewhere.. it does not give me an infinite loop, I just checked the size of the list and it has 524288 at the end of the program - before I put my while loop in it had a size of 20, could this be a problem with the cursor? Or does it point to a problem of how I wrote out my loops?

Comment: `while (iter.hasNext())` along with `iter.add(newTask);` can loop and keep on adding same task for much longer then you unticiapated.

Comment: That could definitely be a factor, is there way to only allow it one task at a time?

Comment: Update, I replaced the while loop with an if statement and am again getting a size of 20, but the order is messed up - I've narrowed it down to the cursor not being moved the correct number of places but am not sure where to go from here